# Most Pathological Object in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

> Complex analysis is the good twin and real analysis the evil one:
>   beautiful formulas and elegant theorems seem to blossom spontaneously
>   in the complex domain, while toil and pathology rule the reals. ~ Charles Pugh

I was just wondering: What is the most pathological object/property you can think of in Complex Analysis?

EDIT: Also posted on MathOverflow as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310418/pathology-in-complex-analysis

Comment: The behaviour of a complex analytic function in a neighbourhood of an essential singularity is insane. (I would also replace "good" by "easy and artificial" and "evil" by "interesting and important" in your value judgment about the twins. $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: After a bit of rewording and context, this would be a decent fit for Math Overflow.

Comment: @Rob Arthan, yes indeed, that's true! About your replacements, yeah I suppose you could think about that but well I just quoted what Charles Pugh said ;p

Comment: @RushabhMehta Hmm, then I'll consider posting it for MathOverflow! Thanks!

Comment: @Kezer: apologies! I didn't notice that the statement was a quotation. I stand by what I said about the value judgment, while appreciating now that it is Pugh's value judgment and not yours. I look forward to seeing the responses you get on MO.

Comment: @Rob No problems!

Comment: Where did you find this quote?

Comment: In the Real Analysis book by Charles Pugh.